# »Bedenken haben«: negativer oder positiver Satzanschluss?

Tags: grammar, usage, negation

Wenn ich ausdrücken möchte, dass ich daran zweifle, dass etwas funktionieren wird: Welcher der folgenden Sätze ist richtig?

> Ich habe Bedenken, dass es funktioniert.
>   Ich habe Bedenken, dass es *nicht* funktioniert.

Oder ist Letzteres eher wie eine doppelte Verneinung zu lesen?

Comment: Klarer wäre: »Ich habe Bedenken. Ich (be)fürchte, dass es nicht funktioniert.«

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Bedenken* hat eine ähnliche Bedeutung wie *Einwand*. Beide richten sich darauf, dass ein erwünschtes Ergebnis weniger wahrscheinlich sein könnte als angenommen. Der *Einwand* zeigt objektiv an, dass ein Argument vorgebracht wird, *Bedenken* geben der Äußerung zusätzlich eine subjektive Färbung. Der negative Charakter der Einschränkung muss entweder durch eine Verneinung oder durch einen Inhalt, der im Kontext verneinend ist, bestätigt werden:

> Ich habe Bedenken, dass es *nicht funktionieren* könnte. Ich habe Bedenken, dass es *zusammenbrechen* könnte.
>
> Seine Bedenken, das Auto könnte durch diese Fahrweise *kaputt werden*, erwiesen sich als grundlos.
>
> Sein Einwand, dass dieser Wagen für eine solche Last *nicht zugelassen* sei, wurde ignoriert.
>
> Sie wandte ein, dass für den Wandertag *schlechtes Wetter* vorhergesagt sei.

"Bedenken, dass es funktioniert", kann daher nur der Saboteur haben, der eigentlich wünscht, dass es nicht funktioniert.

Comment: Oder der Physiker, der die Atombombe eigentlich gar nicht hat bauen wollen ;)

Comment: Super Antwort. Wäre ich selber nie drauf gekommen, wirkt aber total offensichtlich wenn man's erstmal weiß.

Comment: @Emanuel Danke sehr :-)